# how to use Vector of two vectors with optim

Tags: r

I have a wrapper function of two functions. Each function has its own parameters vectors. The main idea is to pass the vectors of parameters (which is a vector or two vectors) to `optim` and then, I would like to maximize the sum of the function.

Since my function is so complex, then I tried to provide a simple example which is similar to my original function. Here is my code:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10,2,0.5)

ff <- function(x, parOpt){
    out  <- -sum(log(dnorm(x, parOpt[[1]][1], parOpt[[1]][2]))+log(dnorm(x,parOpt[[2]][1],parOpt[[2]][2]))) 
    return(out)
}


# parameters in mu,sd vectors arranged in list
params <- c(set1 = c(2, 0.2), set2 = c(0.5, 0.3))

xy <- optim(par = params, fn=ff ,x=x)
```

Which return this error:

```
Error in optim(par = params, fn = ff, x = x) : 
  function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
```

As I understand, I got this error because `optim` cannot pass the parameters to each part of my function. So, how can I tell `optim` that the first vector is the parameter of the first part of my function and the second is for the second part.

Comment: @akrun I am very, very sorry to ask your help about this question. However, it is really very important. So, could you please help me with it. All your comments and help are more appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change method parameter to use initial parameters.
You can read detailed instructions about optim function using ?optim command.
For example you can use "L-BFGS-B" method to use upper and lower constraints.